# is there a way to override version of 'provided' maven dependency?

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project. When I deploy it - the environment (where I deploy it) adds a jar (of dep A) with version 1 to the classpath. Also, I have this dep A with ver 1 in project's pom with provided mvn scope. But I need to use dep A with ver 2 - is there any way to specify this in my pom and force the project to use classes from ver 2 (but not 1)?

As far as I understand I cannot exclude provided jar, so if I just add dep A with ver 2 to pom there will be 2 jars in classpath (ver1,ver2) and dep conflict.

Java 8, mvn 3.5

Comment: Actually `<scope>provided</scope>` means maven will not include this jar into final build. So it is actyaly - exclusion rule. So you have to think about how to upgrade version on your environment.

Comment: "so if I just add dep A with ver 2 to pom there will be 2 jars in classpath (ver1,ver2) and dep conflict" - Yes sort of. Under normal operating circumstances when there are no modules in play, a Java classloader can only load a class once so even if both jars end up in the classpath (one from app, one from env), the classes inside them do not. That's practically worse though because if the layout of the classes changed a lot between the versions, you can get really hard to diagnose classloading errors. Avoid the situation like the plague.

Answer (score 3):

"Provided" means that something external provides it, and that Maven should NOT provide it. Thus it is out of Maven's control.

Maven CAN provide it, but you need to also fix your deployment environment, so that the two versions of the dependency don't conflict.

You can either:

- Make your deployment environment provide the correct version (in which case Maven doesn't need to)
- Remove the dependency from your deployment environment, and make Maven provide it.
- Configure your deployment environment to treat the Maven created deployable as senior to itself, and for its own version to be a fallback only.

Comment: so no way to override from maven(my project) side for 'provided' but just from env side. Thanks!  
in this case, I don't have an access to change the env, so then the only way left is to teach my project work with old ver 1

Comment: @pas8sion Correct. How could Maven override your deployment env? It has no knowledge of this.